# GHCI - Failed to load interface for

Tags: haskell, ghci

To reproduce git clone https://github.com/ndmitchell/hoogle and in `stack repl`:

```
λ > :l src/Hoogle.hs 
[ 1 of 27] Compiling Input.Settings   ( src/Input/Settings.hs, interpreted )

src/Input/Settings.hs:17:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for ‘Paths_hoogle’
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

This seems to be caused by `Paths_hoogle` being a hidden-modules but I do not know what the solution is to get `src/Hoogle.hs` to load.

Comment: Which version of stack are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The `hoogle` project does not have a `stack.yaml`, so `stack` does not recognize that it is in a project. `stack repl` and `stack ghci` will open a GHCi environment in the implicit global project.

It might be wise for `stack` to check for a `.cabal` file in the current directory and warn if it's not in a `stack` project.

I was able to load the library by doing `stack init` to generate an initial `stack.yaml` file. Then `stack repl` and `stack ghci` both worked fine, loading both exposed *and* hidden modules.

Comment: Yup, this is the issue.  Parsons matt helpfully opened up a github issue on the topic, and I've added a warning for this circumstance that describes actions to resolve it - https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/3544

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to run GHCI repl using:

```
cabal repl lib:hoogle
```

This automatically loaded the Hoogle module:

```
Ok, modules loaded: Action.CmdLine, Action.Generate, Action.Search, Action.Server, Action.Test, General.Conduit, General.IString, General.Log, General.Store, General.Str, General.Template, General.Timing, General.Util, General.Web, Hoogle, Input.Cabal, Input.Download, Input.Haddock, Input.Item, Input.Reorder, Input.Set, Input.Settings, Output.Items, Output.Names, Output.Tags, Output.Types, Paths_hoogle, Query.
λ > defaultDatabaseLocation 
"/home/neo/.hoogle/default-haskell-5.0.13.hoo"
```